# Get a string between two variable strings that contain regex specific characters using python

Tags: python, regex

so I have a string such as this:

```
r'irrelevant data (~symbol)relevant data(/~symbol) irrelevant data'
```

and want to get to the relevant data. However, the (~symbol) tag is variable, meaning that in order to find the relevant regex phrase we would need to go something like

```
tags = ["(~symbol)","(/~symbol)"]
string = r'irrelevant data (~symbol)relevant data(/~symbol) irrelevant data'
regex = r'{}([^"]*){}'.format(tags[0],tags[1])
result = re.findall(regex , string)[0]
```

the problem is that our tags contain characters that would need to be escaped if used in a regular expression, so in this case the result would contain the tags themselves instead of just the desired string.

Is there a good solution that doesn't involve replace?

Comment: I'm not sure what the actual data looks like but I think something like this would pick up the relevant data: `re.findall(r'.+\(.+\)(.+)\(.+\)', string)` without needing a replace. Add salt to taste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot in your question, so I'll try addressing them one-by-one:

- For getting the "irrelevant data" in between, you might want to look into [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split).
- For separators with special characters, use [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape).
- To exclude the separators in the result, use non-capturing groups (`?:`).

For your example, it would be something like this:

```py
import re
patterns = ["(~symbol)", "(/~symbol)"]
string = r'irrelevant data (~symbol)relevant data(/~symbol) irrelevant data'
result = re.split('(?:' + '|'.join(map(re.escape, patterns)) + ')', string)
```

which then gives

```
['irrelevant data ', 'relevant data', ' irrelevant data']
```